# Set the mode for next boot from the terminal

Tags: macos, startup, reboot

I'd like to be able to boot into the recovery mode the next time the machine boots ***not by using the start up key presses***. I'm already logged in in normal user mode - can I set this in the terminal?

Any help with this is much appreciated.

Comment: You'd probably have to use the `sudo bless -mount /Volumes/Startup_Disk_Name -setBoot` terminal command, but you'll have to find out how to specify the recovery mode partition. Use `diskutil list` command to find the partitions.

Comment: @IconDaemon That worked. I found the disk using `diskutil list` and then mounted with `diskutil mount disk03` and then your suggestion with the `-nextonly` flag too. If you add an answer I'll give you the cred, it's how I found the full list of commands [here](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/option-boot-password-lock-help.1631053/#post-17835441). Many thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you used `disk03`? I'm looking at my `diskutil list` and I see no disks in the identifier column with that leading zero. I have a Fusion internal drive and three externals. `disk0` and `disk1` are fused into `disk 2`. The externals are `disk3, disk4, disk5`. The hard path to the drives in /dev also have no leading zero.

Comment: @IconDaemon No, I just picked that from the example, it's whatever the `diskutil list` says it was, I'm not near that machine right now so I couldn't check. But it was 3 in the list. Very similar though whatever it was.